# Mediawiki: internal link with parameters?

Tags: links, mediawiki, url-parameters

How do you write an internal link with parameters?

I have a stored query from external data and would like to link readers to the semantic internal object that stores the query. However the query is slow to open so I would like a link that will open the page on which the query is run to open in edit mode.

I tried to add `&action=edit` to the link to the internal object but it didn't open the page in edit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internal links with parameters are best written with the [magic word](http://mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words) `fullurl`, e.g. `[{{fullurl:Page|action=edit}} edit Page]`.

If I understand correctly, you want to take an [inline query](https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Inline_queries) (Ask) like

```
{{#ask: [[Category:City]] [[located in::Germany]]
  | limit=3
}}
```

and get a link to its "edit query" panel. The easiest would be to add `limit=0` and let the user click, otherwise you have to make the link yourself like

```
{{fullurl:Special:Ask|q=...|eq=yes}}
```

But if you want users to systematically customise your query, perhaps you're actually looking for an [InputBox](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:InputBox)?